# Question about Alexa Dialog Directives: addElicitSlotDirective() - Slot eliciting

Tags: dialog, alexa-skills-kit, slot, alexa-interaction-model

I have a fairly simple question that I believe should have a straight forward answer, but I can't seem to find it in the documentation.

My question is:

Does "addElicitSlotDirective" elicit a slot from the current intent from where it's called or does it elicit a slot form the update intent?

Thanks in advance!